# Write to any Edittext when Focus - Android

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext, calculator

I have a simple calculator app. A numpad made of buttons and I show the result on one edittext. Now what I want to do is to have 3 edittext, means 3 results. So when I click press/focus to any of the edittext. I can type nos. on the numpad and post it to any of the 3 edittext. It works for one edittext now, how can I make it work to all the edittext?Here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public String str ="";

 Character op = 'q';
 int i,num,numtemp;
    EditText showResult;
    String displayStr = "";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

        showResult = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.result_id);
        showResult1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.result_id1);
        showResult2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.result_id2);


    }
      public void btn1Clicked(View v){
       insert(1);

      }

 public void btn2Clicked(View v){
       insert(2);

      }
      public void btn3Clicked(View v){
       insert(3);

      }
      public void btn4Clicked(View v){
       insert(4);

      }
      public void btn5Clicked(View v){
       insert(5);

      }
      public void btn6Clicked(View v){
       insert(6);
      }
      public void btn7Clicked(View v){
       insert(7);

      }
      public void btn8Clicked(View v){
       insert(8);

      }
      public void btn9Clicked(View v){
       insert(9);

      }

      public void btn0Clicked(View v){
           insert(0);

          }


      public void btnplusClicked(View v){
       perform();
       op = '+';
       displayStr += "+";
       showResult.setText(displayStr);
      }

 public void btnminusClicked(View v){
     perform();
        op = '-';
        displayStr += "-";    
        showResult.setText(displayStr);
      }
      public void btndivideClicked(View v){
       perform();
       op = '/';
       displayStr += "/";
       showResult.setText(displayStr);
      }
      public void btnmultiClicked(View v){
       perform();
       op = '*';
       displayStr += "*";
       showResult.setText(displayStr);
      }
      public void btnequalClicked(View v){



          calculate();

      }

 public void btnclearClicked(View v){
       reset();
      }
      private void reset() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   str ="";
   op ='q';
   num = 0;
   numtemp = 0;
   displayStr = "";
   showResult.setText("");
 }

 private void insert(int j) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       str = str+Integer.toString(j);
       num = Integer.valueOf(str).intValue();        
       displayStr += Integer.toString(j); 
       showResult.setText(displayStr);

   }
      private void perform() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    str = "";
    numtemp = num;
   }




      private void calculate() {


          if(op == '+')
     num = numtemp+num;
    else if(op == '-')
     num = numtemp-num;
    else if(op == '/')
     num = numtemp/num;
    else if(op == '*')
     num = numtemp*num;


showResult.setText(""+num);

   }

}
```

Comment: i think you need [onFocusChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html)

Comment: @shayanpourvatan How can I do that with my code? I tried doing that but it doesn't work. I think im doing the onFocusChangeListener wrong Can you please help me with my code.

Comment: you must add that to all `editText` view like: `showResult.onFocusChangeListener();` and so on

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Hope it will helps you.

Programatically:

```
edittext.requestFocus();
```

Through xml:

```
<EditText...>
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Or call onClick method manually.

Comment: No. This is not what I'm asking. I want to choose where I want to show the results between the 3 edittext. Like when I click the edittext, it shows the focus and thats where I should type.

Comment: try to add this line into your xml. android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Do this for every `EditText`

```
showResult.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            showResult.requestFocus();
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.showSoftInput(showResult, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        }
    });
```

Comment: not working. Im using buttons for the numpad. And I just want to choose any edittext when i click the buttons

Comment: @jandroid when clicking that pirticular button add that there like codes. showResult is one of your edittext. to like that for remaining.

Comment: @jandroid yes post it.

Comment: Look at my code up there..the insert() statement. I display the numbers from numpad buttons to showResult.setText(displayStr); How the numpad will know if what edittext should it be posted? There are three edittext.

Comment: Look at my code up there..the insert() statement. I display the numbers from numpad buttons to showResult.setText(displayStr); How the numpad will know if what edittext should it be posted? There are three edittext..

Comment: @jandroid use `showResult.requestFocus();` that time numpad will Focus showResult EditText

Answer (score 0):

Dude , this question related to logic not an android issue
But
You can use a variable

```
int i=0;

when first edittext is clicked just changed to i=1
second edittext is clicked just changed to i=2
thirdedittext is clicked just changed to i=3
so when result button is clicked just check the value of i 
and print the result in respective edittext
```